# Sample Credit Card processing

Tags: php, credit-card

Can anyone direct me to a place where I can find a mock implementation of Credit Card processing system, using mySql and PHP??? Just want to check out how the system works, using some sample credit card numbers and stuff.

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK every bank can give you a test-account only for developing process and no a simple out-of-the-box solution exists.

Comment: WHat kind of CC processing? Simply accepting a CC on an ecommerce site, or full-fledge general processing handling transactions for others?

Answer (score 5):

Each implementation has some specific sample cards. Like Paypal or google Checkout. Apart of this each CC company has its own.

- American Express, 3400 0000 0000 009
- Carte Blanche, 3000 0000 0000 04
- Discover, 6011 0000 0000 0004
- Diner's Club, 3000 0000 0000 04
- enRoute, 2014 0000 0000 009
- JCB, 2131 0000 0000 0008
- MasterCard, 5500 0000 0000 0004
- Solo, 6334 0000 0000 0004
- Switch, 4903 0100 0000 0009
- Visa, 4111 1111 1111 1111

Paypal:

- American Express, 378282246310005
- American Express, 371449635398431
- American Express Corporate, 378734493671000
- Australian BankCard, 5610591081018250
- Diners Club, 30569309025904
- Diners Club, 38520000023237
- Discover, 6011111111111117
- Discover, 6011000990139424
- JCB, 3530111333300000
- JCB, 3566002020360505
- MasterCard, 5555555555554444
- MasterCard, 5105105105105100
- Visa, 4111111111111111
- Visa, 4012888888881881
- Visa, 4222222222222
  (Note: Even though this number has a different character count than the other test numbers, it is the correct and functional number.)

Processor-specific Cards

- Dankort (PBS), 76009244561
- Dankort (PBS), 5019717010103742
- Switch/Solo (Paymentech), 6331101999990016

[Google checkout test cards](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API_Credit_Card_Test_Cases.html).

Comment: Dankort (PBS), 76009244561, seems wrong.  Maybe there's a typo in the last digit.  Try 76009244567.

Answer (score 0):

An outline, note: different providers may or may not ask further steps.

- You maintain users' cart on your site
- On checkout you'll generating a token (algorithm provided by the bank)
- User enters his/her card details **on the bank's website**
- You'll get the result from the bank so now you know where to go now (success, fail)

Comment: What I meant was a mock credit card processing system that uses the card numbers we have already stored in the mySQL database and their available credit limit. I'm not looking for an actual implementation to accept payments. So, if you can, then please let me know.

Comment: You can't store cc numbers because you even can't see them. The only one who can actually see them is the bank application.